# use txt file az input, line by line PYTHON

Tags: python, text, input

i need a code in python 2.7, to use txt file as a input. i dont know how many lines is in my file. but my lines follow a rule.
each line contains name;age;sex
for example test.txt is:

```
mary;24;f

alex;32;m

nina;45;f

jack;20;m
```

i must read line by line and Initialize my variables.
how can i read this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("input") as f:
  for line in f:
    name, age, gender = line.split(';')
    print name, age, gender
```

Note that this simple example does not deal with badly formatted lines (eg, your sample input has blank lines).  You'll probably want to wrap this in a try/except or otherwise deal with incorrect input.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I have found doing it...

```
with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", "r") as myfile:
for line in myfile:
    print line
```